# PHP Laravel - multi-locale routing with LaravelGettext?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

It seems I really got myself into the rabbit hole with this one. I'm tasked to implement localization into a Laravel project by using LaravelGettext (since this seems to be only one with PO file support). The routing requirements seem quite simple, everytime a page URL is called e.g. like this:

```
https://page.com/user
```

With e.g. `de` as fallback/cached session locale, it is supposed to redirect to:

```
https://page.com/de/user
```

unless a valid locale prefix is already defined inside the URL manually. Every subsequent URL from there on is supposed to have the same locale prefix, unless changed.

The concept seems simple, but implementing as required has turned into hours of googling for me for how to set up the routes correctly. Approaches like

```
routes\web.php

    Route::prefix('{locale?}')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {
        //all routes go here
    });


App\Middleware\Locale

    ...

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $locale = $request->segment(1);

        if (!in_array($locale, config('laravel-gettext.supported-locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $fallback = session('locale') ?: config('laravel-gettext.fallback-locale');
            $segments = array_prepend($segments, $fallback);
            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        session(['locale' => $locale]);
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        LaravelGettext::setLocale($locale);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

unfortunately fail with URLs having multiple segments, since the prefix misinterprets them. Optional prefixes aren't well recommended either.

Can someone recommend me a reliable solution? I'm getting really frustrated over this.

Comment: I suspect having the locale as a uri segment will result in numerous headaches so assuming it's a hard requirement of your task (as opposed to just dropping it in a subdomain), have you tried adding a global constraint to your locale uri segment so that it only responds to the locales you are expecting?  Presumably that would help with the prefix misinterpreting URLs with multiple segments.

Comment: I already used to have a similiar solution, with locale checking completely outsourced to the RouteServiceProvider. As for resolving links without locale prefix, I was suggested to catch a HttpNotFoundException inside the Exceptions\Handler class and redirect (301) to the same link with the fallback locale prefix. This had the weird problem though that the default locale somehow had been cached and overrid the locales in the session and for LaravelGettext somehow... couldn't figure out what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. It is my old way when I was using gettext. This is routes.php

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

if(in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))){
    Config::set('app.locale', $locale);
    if($locale=='bg') $gettext_locale = 'bg_BG';
    if($locale=='en') $gettext_locale = 'en_US';
    if($locale=='ru') $gettext_locale = 'ru_RU';
    if($locale=='ro') $gettext_locale = 'ro_RO';
    if($locale=='sk') $gettext_locale = 'sr_RS';
    if($locale=='mk') $gettext_locale = 'mk_MK';
    LaravelGettext::setLocale($gettext_locale);
}else{ // default locale
    Config::set('app.locale', 'bg');
    LaravelGettext::setLocale('bg_BG');

    $locale = '';
}
Route::group([
    'prefix' => $locale
], function(){...}
```

Now I am using database like this: https://gist.github.com/escapeboy/b50f252f095916963e8130bc9dc69f56